# Trying to set a conditional within a jQuery blur() event

Tags: javascript, jquery, blur

I'm trying to get an input box to perform on blur() either set a value of 0.000 if the value entered is an empty string and if it isn't then perform some function. This is what I have. Help me out here, I don't know the appropriate syntax on how to do this.

```
jQuery("#10kt-weight").blur(function(){
        if(valueOf("#10kt-weight") == "") {
            jQuery("#10kt-weight").val("0.000");
        } else {
            calc_value();
        }
    });
```

Comment: http://www.jqapi.com is your new best friend

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery("#10kt-weight").blur(function(){
        if(jQuery("#10kt-weight").val() === "") {
            jQuery("#10kt-weight").val("0.000");
        } else {
            calc_value();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your function is executed by the `.blur()` method, using `this` inside the function will refer to `#10kt-weight`, you can get the actual value of your element with `jQuery(this).val()` (or `this.value`) Try this:

```
jQuery("#10kt-weight").blur(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == "") {
            jQuery(this).val("0.000");
        } else {
            calc_value();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with jQuery.trim() to trim spaces and .length to check if there are characters after trim the input value

```
jQuery("#10kt-weight").blur(function(){
    if(jQuery.trim(jQuery(this)).length) {
        jQuery(this).val("0.000");
    } else {
        calc_value();
    }
});
```